# Missing Organization Feature: Event__c.Sharing

Tags: managed-package, sharing, package-install

I am trying to upgrade a package in a subscriber org.  This org has a locally created custom object, Event__c.

I get the following error message:

> Missing Organization Feature: Event__c.Sharing Custom Object Records
>   Package install error
>   There are problems that prevent this package from being installed.

The new version of the package has a brand new custom object, nsPrefix_*Event*_c.

From reading around, I believe that this message is saying that the new Event object is private, so private sharing settings must be present.  And yet this is a brand new object so I can't see why it would fail there.  This is a package that has already been installed successfully many times.

The only possibility I can think of is that SFDC gets confused between Event_*c (Controlled By Parent) and nsPrefix*_Event__c (Private) and thinks they are the same object.  Could this be happening here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SFDC Case Response

> I am following up your case number xxxxxxx.
>
> Please be advise that I consulted our Backline Engineer and he
>   identified that this currently reported as a known issue (Bug). Also,
>   this issue has been reported on R&D team and they are still reviewing
>   the final details but please know that currently, there are no
>   tentative date for the fix at this time.
>
> For the interim please use the workaround by changing the sharing
>   settings.
>
> We do apologize for the inconvenience regarding this concern.
>
> The solution initially provided by SFDC support was to:
>   1. You can make the Event_c sharing settings to private BEFORE you install the package. THEN change it back to its original state
>   (Controlled by Parent) once done installing.
>
> OR
>
> 1. Rename the object Event_c because it is not recommended to name custom object the same as standard Event object name.

A few comments
- We can't change sharing settings from Controlled By Parent since it is the detail of a master-detail relationship
- Asking the client to change the API Name of one of their local objects is absurd since there can be thousands of dependencies.
- "it is not recommended to name custom object the same as standard Event object name" <- the issue here is not with the standard Event object, it is with a locally created Event custom object and a package Event custom object.  I would love to know how they think we can enforce this "recommendation".

Answer (score 0):

If the custom object's name is Event__c, then yes, SF can get "confused" with the API name. You can log a case to get more details, but if you change the API name you might be able fix this. Give it a try.